# Удаление разделов диска OS X

Tags: macos, диск, разметка-диска

Подскажите, как удалить раздел виртуальной машины (VM) и желательно раздел "Не подключено"? Машина не используется и вообще удалена давно.

[image: Дисковая утилита OS X]

Answer (score 0):

**Я использовал GParted Live.** Цитирую описание: " GParted Live — мощное средство для проведения различных операций с разделами жестких дисков: создания, уничтожения, изменения размера, перемещения, проверки и копирования. Этот инструмент необходим при создании пространства для новых операционных систем, реорганизации использования диска, копировании данных и т.д.

GParted Live работает с любым из существующих накопителей,‭ ‬будь то‭ ‬IDE,‭ ‬SATA, Flash drive‭ ‬или даже‭ ‬SSD-накопитель и поддерживаем большинство распространенных файловых систем.‭ ‬Особенностью программы является ее исполнение в виде образа,‭ ‬что еще больше упрощает работу.
Основные возможности GParted Live:

— Создание и редактирование разделов.
— Работа в режиме‭ ‬LiveCD‭ ‬с любого носителя.
— Работа с любой операционной системой.
— Собственная система безопасности,‭ ‬позволяющая выполнить‭ ‬откат действия,‭ ‬приводящего к нестабильности или краху системы.
— Поддержка файловых систем ext2,‭ ‬ext3,‭ ‬ext4,‭ ‬FAT16,‭ ‬FAT32,‭ ‬HFS,‭ ‬HFS+,‭ ‬NTFS,‭ ‬UFS...
Недостатки:
    Освоение требует времени"

Вот ссылка : https://gparted.org/livecd.php